# how to get the information from the cell which is being clicked in collectionview

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

hello I have implemented a  `UICollectionView` in my controller. There are lots of info I am displaying on each cell. When user clicks the particular cell I want to pass all the info that was in the cell to another controller.

As I am displaying all the data from db in the cells and cells are generating dynamically so I think one way could be to pass just a record id from one cell to this function `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` and then in the second controller I query again from the database. But I think that would not be the good idea. and also I don't know how can I pass the id or any info here in this function `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`.

So in short I want to display all the info in another  controller that is being displayed in that cell which is being clicked

here is my code

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath
        indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell",
                forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CardsCollectionCell
            cell.usernameLabel.text = (((dict["\(indexPath.item)"] as?NSDictionary)!["Trip"] as?NSDictionary)!["userName"] as?NSString)! as String
            cell.feeLabel.text = (((dict["\(indexPath.item)"] as?NSDictionary)!["Trip"] as?NSDictionary)!["fee"] as?NSString)! as String

             return cell
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

      }
```

Comment: Hey I would suggest that you create a model class to share data between different views. It will be more easier than passing the whole information on the selection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So let's going to explain by parts, the `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` delegate method is used to know what `UICollectionViewCell` was tapped in the `UICollectionViewController`, you can get the `UICollectionViewCell` very easily using the method `cellForItemAtIndexPath`(it's not the same as `collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath`) like in the following code:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = self.collectionView?.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)  as! CardsCollectionCell
    // access to any property inside the cell you have.
    // cell.usernameLabel.text
}
```

So regarding ***in short I want to display all the info in another controller that is being displayed in that cell which is being clicked***

You can use the `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` method without any problem to launch a manual segue using the method `performSegueWithIdentifier` to another `UIViewController` and just in the `prepareForSegue` pass any data you need to pass to the another `UIViewController`. See the following code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
   // the identifier of the segue is the same you set in the Attributes Inspector
   self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segueName", sender: self)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

   if(segue.identifier == "segueName") {
      // this is the way of get the indexPath for the selected cell
      let indexPath = self.collectionView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
      let row = indexPath.row

      // get a reference to the next UIViewController
      let nextVC = segue.destinationViewController as! NameOfYourViewController
   } 
}
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. okay I understand the concept now. Now my second question is okay I get the index path here let indexPath = self.collectionView.indexPathForSelectedRow() .. lets say I have displayed username in any cell. how can I get the username here in prepareforsegue  of that cell ???

Comment: You need to have some dataSource from where you have populating your `UICollectionView` isn't, you have the `indexPath.row` so you have the index for the dataSource.

Comment: sorry didn't understand much. yes I think I have the datasource. okay as you see in the code how I am getting the data and showing it. by seeing it how you get the username or any variable here in indexpath.row ?

Comment: I suppose that as you put in your code `(((dict["\(indexPath.row)"] as?NSDictionary)!["Trip"] as?NSDictionary)!["userName"] as?NSString)! as String` if the keys of `dict` are of String type of course if not just pass the Int returned in `indexPath.row`